# Spring boot dependency injection for value

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, inner-classes

I am a newbee here and I have one question on Spring Boot.

I have the following classes:

```
ClassA
{
    LocalDate d1; 
    LocalDate d2; 
    List<ClassB> bList;
    List<ClassC> cList;
    //.. and a few more such List attributes
}

ClassB
{

    //Certain logic for which I need LocalDate d1 and LocalDate d2.
}

ClassC
{

    //Certain logic for which I need LocalDate d1 and LocalDate d2.
}
```

Classes B and C have a certain logic for which I need "LocalDate d1" and "LocalDate d2" from ClassA. Basically, imagine ClassB and ClassC also have local "LocalDate d1" and local "LocalDate d2" variables, but values for these should be same as ClassA values.

> Question: What is the best way to pass "LocalDate d1" and "LocalDate
>   d2" values to ClassB and ClassC.

- I do not want to use InnerClass. (Too big classes and too many of
  them)
- I can not make "LocalDate d1" and "LocalDate d2" static, as
  there will be many instances of ClassA each with different "LocalDate
  d1" and "LocalDate d2"

Without Dependency Injection, I would have manually instantiated bList inside ClassA and would have passed (LocalDate d1, LocalDate d2) as constructor parameter to each instance that I add to the bList. But how to achieve this with dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

`LocalDate` seems like a bad candidate for dependency injection as it does not contain any custom logic.

It often gets generated as a result of some action, API response, DB fetch, data messaging etc etc.

These actions are what should be injected by the spring container and not the raw results that they might return.